# Is it possible tu run encrypted code on amazon AWS servers?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I a have a powerful and valuable machine learning algorithm written in python and I would like to protect it, is it posssible to encrypt my code with https://www.sourcedefender.co.uk/ and run on amazon aws service?

Comment: You can and should simply try it out. My expectation: yes, of course you can run the code, why not, it is normal python code at the end of the day. Wether or not a tool like that has *any* benefit / point to it is a different question :D

Comment: I have an EXTREMELY POWERFUL IDEA. I wanna use all means to protect my idea so surely there is an obvious benefit running an emcrypted code ...

Comment: No, there is no benefit to run encrypted code because to run it it needs to be decrypted first and at that point you have unencrypted code :) But go ahead and pay for it if it makes you feel better. Otherwise you need to define actual attack vectors, who do you want to protect it against and why? Why not use legal instead of tech to protect your IP? Etc, etc, etc.... but as I said this is a separate issue and one that generally is off-topic.

Comment: Is there any encryption method able to run a code without unencrypting? I mean a way to run the computations like a black-box with nobody able to perform reverse engineering and discover what is inside the encrypted code...

Comment: How exactly would that work?  The Python interpreter has to run Python code.  Any code that is encrypted must eventually be presented to the interpreter.  If your code is really that valuable and you're that worried about it then a public cloud may not be the right solution.  You're asking about a theoretical ability for someone to get a hold of your code.  Your local development environment is likely more dangerous than a public cloud.

Comment: I will give an example: Suppose I will have to multiply two dense matrices and a vector of size nxn and n. The "black-blox" part of my algorithm will preprocess the dense matrices and the vector, in a secret way nobody can read or make reverse engineering, outputing some entries of the vector output able to solve my machine learning algorithm. The complexity will be much faster than $O(n^2)$ for naive dense matrix multiplication. This is why I wanna keep secret about my algorithm.

Comment: „in a secret way nobody can read or make reverse engineering“ - that is simply impossible unless you weaken the constraint. Anyway what you actually is obfuscation but do not expect too much from it.

Comment: If you want to keep it a secret from the rest of the world then you can run it on a machine that is 100% under your control and off the grid (local machine not connected to the internet). If you insist on running it on lambda then restrict access to that lambda accordingly and protect your aws login info. You will have to read their ToS to see if Amazon can or does access lambda code. Otherwise, you are **** out of luck

Answer (score 0):

An Amazon EC2 instance is a virtual computer that runs an Operating System just like any other computer. So, you can run anything on an EC2 instance that you can run on a normal computer.

If you are concerned about people being able to access the code running on the EC2 instance, then use standard security precautions such as:

- Restricting access via **Password / Keypair**
- Limiting access to specific IP addresses by using a **Security Group**
- Encrypting the **Amazon EBS volume** where your code is stored
- Restricting access / encrypting **code in the repository** where your code is being stored (eg don't put it in GitHub)
- Using [Multi-Factor Authentication](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_mfa.html) to protect access to your AWS Account